# How would I overlay text onto an image using imagick in either C or Go?

Tags: c, image, text, go, imagick

I'm actually using the [Go bindings](https://github.com/GroundSix/imagick) for imagick. Online there aren't really any docs specifically for this but that's okay I can read the C docs and in some cases even the PHP ones; they are all *fairly* similar.

I would like to use `AnnotateImage` method, which does currently work:

```
c.magickWand.ReadImage("example.jpg")
c.magickWand.SetImageMatte(false)
c.drawingWand.SetFont(c.font)

//c.drawingWand.SetFontSize(c.fontSize)

c.pixelWand.SetColor("black")
c.drawingWand.SetFillColor(c.pixelWand)

c.drawingWand.SetGravity(imagick.GRAVITY_CENTER)
c.magickWand.AnnotateImage(c.drawingWand, 0, 0, 0, "This is my text!")
c.magickWand.WriteImage(c.newImageName)
```

So my code so far looks a bit like the above ^

This is all Go, but method names are pretty much the same in C, and in some cases PHP. The above actually works fine. It will put the text in the centre of the image, but I don't want to specify the font size, and I don't want the text in the centre of the image.

Ideally I would like the text to be towards the bottom of the image, and for imagick to choose the best font size based on the size it has to work with. I know it is somehow possible, I've been close, however I can't get to the bottom of this.

Comment: In regards to the above: assume `c.font` and `c.newImageName` have already been defined.

Comment: To avoid having the text in the center of the image, did you try to don't use GRAVITY_CENTER? https://github.com/GroundSix/imagick/blob/master/imagick/gravity_type.go